# How to assign task to CompletableFuture so thats once picked up, it shouldn't be picked up again

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, completable-future

I've few tasks like these:

```
            public static String task1()    
            public static String task2() 
            public static String task3()
            public static String task4()
            public static String task5()
            public static String task6()
```

I want to execute these tasks by using CompletableFuture in parallel but in async way with an executor :

```
    CompletableFuture<Object> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> executeTask(), executor);   
    CompletableFuture<Object> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> executeTask(), executor);
    CompletableFuture<Object> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> executeTask(), executor);
```

executeTask() is the method which retrieves the task to be executed, now the problem is when I start executing the above code then task1() is picked up by all the future1,future2 and future3 and task2 is picked up by all because all futures are running in parallel and in async way. 
What I wanted - once a task is picked up by any Future Object, is shouldn't be picked up others. How do I achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code of executeTask(), what it does: There is a map (static TreeMap> map = new TreeMap<>();) which contains the method name and method to be returned as Tasks like task1, task2 etc.. Now what I am doing here: I am iterating the map and finding the that entry which doesn't have key status that means this task can be executed and returned and before returning I am putting status key so that it can't be picked up again. Now all the futures are running as async thats why all of them picking task1 together and so on.

```
public static Object executeTask()
{
    Object result = null;

    try
    {
        Method method = null;

        for(Entry<String, HashMap<String, Method>> en : map.entrySet())
        {
            if(!en.getValue().containsKey("status"))
            {
                System.out.println("Found free task: "+en.getKey().toString());
                method = en.getValue().get(en.getKey());
                en.getValue().put("status", ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture.class.getMethod("toString"));

                break;
            }
        }

        if(method != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Executing : "+method.getName());
            result = (String) method.invoke(new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture());
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the executeTask() return the actual task only once and a task which does nothing after being called more than once.

You can use synchronized, a Lock, or an AtomicReference to the task (I would do the last one)

Comment: executeTask() is returning a task which needs to be picked up by Futures, there is a recursion returned in method executeTask() so that every time there should be a task returned as long there is any. I am not sure how to restrict this. some more information would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar if you want the task to only be performed once, you should only return that task once. Are you saying you can't change the code? I am not sure what is preventing you.

Comment: I've added code of executeTask, which is being called all the time to return the task, I am not sure what change I can do there. Can you please take a look at it once again,

Comment: @PankajKatiyar where is map being set? You could pass an Atomic Integer which you increment and only do something if the count was 0.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out the solution, let me describe this in this way: I've a map it contains the TaskName and Task, to execute these I've used three instances of CompletableFuture, these future execute the same method executeTask(). executeTask() iterates the map and get the task which has key=status and that is executed. Now the problem is due to parallel execution, all futures executes the executeTask() together and same task is returned to all futures. Now I am not sure where do I use AtomicInt, I tried but didn't work, if you can point me where to put check. Thanks

Comment: Also I can not make executeTask() to return task only once coz this is the method which iterates the map and return the tasks.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar you pass the same Atomic Integer to all three calls. Only one thread will be able to increment the value from 0 to 1.